# Why does hypothesis of SVM output 0 or 1?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm

Prof. Andrew Ng in his Machine Learning class says that *unlike* Logistic Regression, SVM outputs hypothesis as 1 or 0. But I don’t understand why SVM's behavior differs from that of logistic regression even though both these algorithms use the same sigmoid function?

In other words, $h(x)$ for Logistic Regression is continuous: $0 \le h(x) \le 1$. But $h(x)$ for SVM is discrete: $h(x) = \{0, 1\}.$

Why?

Comment: It is hard determine what your "why" is trying to ask.  By their very construction, logistic regression outputs log odds and SVM outputs a binary classification. Beyond that fundamental (obvious and trivial) observation, what more are you looking for?

Comment: Here's an analogy: I can build a spoon out of metal or I can build a fork out of metal. They're both made of metal, but they're shaped differently.

Comment: It is unfortunate that SVM classifiers are often thought of as yielding *only* binary labels. The SVM decision value that is always implicitly generated is far more informative. Binary labels are merely thresholded decision values.

Comment: @MarcClaesen what exactly distance to the separating hyperplane measures? How it can be used if different cases when variables have different levels of measurements?

Answer (score 1):

SVM can output distance to the separating hyperplane, which is not an probability but other metric. It can also ouput class probability via Platts methods.

Basic output from the logistic regression is of course logit, which can be transformed into probability and when used with loss function L(T(c,b)) can be used as a basis for decision. In loss function threshold T is a function of costs and benefits associated with various misclassifications/correct classifications.